# Showing Dashboard/Report in object's layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, dashboard, custom-reports

I have a requirement where I need to show a dashboard in object's related list.How can this be achieved?

I am having a Report Type Created on Reports,I have created the report and dashboard for the same.

I created a new Section in the Opportunity Layout,and added the Report Chart there,but it is just not appearing.

Is it really necessary to have this report called from a visualforce page?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

yes you are correct,You need to create one Visual force page and there you need to populate the dashboard like below : -

```
<img height="100%" width="100%" src="{!imageUrl}"  />
```

In class you need to populate the url of the dashboard.

I think this will solve your purpose.